# Mobile Safari <select> element mysteriously shows multiple selections

Tags: javascript, html, ios, html-select

This is a bad question because I can't offer any sort of reproducible example.  However, I haven't found any reference to the behavior I'm seeing anywhere, so I figured this is my best bet.

I've got a trio of `<select>` elements set up as a date selection mechanism. There are some event handlers behind them to do things like update the list of days when the month or year change, but that's about it. The elements themselves are totally simple:

```
<select class="day required">
  <option value="1">01</option>
  <option value="2">02</option>
  <option value="3">03</option>
  <option value="4">04</option>
  <option value="5">05</option>
  <option value="6">06</option>
  <option value="7">07</option>
  <option value="8">08</option>
  <option value="9">09</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

(copied straight out of the Chrome developer tools).  So that's the `Day` selection, and it's the one that's giving me bizarre behavior (sometimes) on iOS (and only iOS).

When I tap on that `<select>` directly (the `Day`, that is), there's no problem; it works just fine. However, when I tap first on the `Month` selection to its left, and then get to the `Day` by clicking the `Next` button in the pop-up Safari *pick an option* interface, then things get weird. What happens is that the option texts all show up, as usual.  If I "roll" the list up or down a ways such that the currently-selected option is not visible (so like, from day `5` to day `15`), and then click another selection, well that works insofar as the newly-selected `<option>` entry gets a checkmark by it, but if I roll the list back to the original one, it's still checked!  It's possible to repeat the process a few times to the point where there are checkmarks all over the place.

When I click the blue `Done` button, only one entry is actually selected; you'll note that there's no "multiple" attribute on the element.  The same HTML works fine of course in desktop browsers and in Android; oddly enough, we've seen the same problem in Chrome on iOS.

I've tried disabling the event handlers experimentally, but that has no effect. I've tried making jsfiddle/jsbin examples without success either.  The page this code appears on is not simple but it's not wildly complex; the most interesting thing about it is that the markup is all dynamically generated by a JavaScript template system, but that all works fine across all sorts of stuff without any comparable weirdness.

Since I don't see console errors and it seems independent of whether I handle "change" events or not, *and* because it *only* happens when I get to the `<select>` in a certain way, I'm inclined to thing that this is just a corner-case bug with the low-level widget used by WebKit for `<select>` elements (on iOS), and not a problem with my code per se.  Of course, if there's a workaround I'd be delighted to try it, but none of the random alterations I've made so far have had any effect.

Anybody else seen this?

Another couple of details: when it's acting strangely, taps on the options always correctly update the element on the page.  Sometimes there's no "click" sound, but sometimes there is. When I click between options without rolling the list up or down, then within the subset of options I can see the widget starts working properly again, but non-visible options may remain checked.

Comment: If I can get a jsBin repro of this I'll post it of course.

Comment: @canon because there's no way to put limits on what dates can be selected. The spec says that the "min" and "max" attributes are supposed to control that, but Safari pays no attention to those attributes.

Comment: This sounds more like an iOS or WebKit bug than a problem with your code. Try filing a bug report with Apple and see what they say.

Comment: Could it be because you don't have names or id's on your select elements and one of the underlying scripts handles events for select elements in general?

Comment: @ReinierKaper I don't think so; it doesn't seem to have anything to do with events. I actually haven't tried fooling with this lately; it's possible that an iOS update has fixed it since I wrote this 6 months ago.